# No active exception to reraise

Tags: python, python-unittest

A brief background first.
I have to run some unit tests. Only issue is that the client wants the failed tests to be reported in form of a word document with some additional information which I can add easily. 
What I have done till now is this.

I have written a small function which will write stuff in a word document using python-docx. 
The idea was that I will catch the exception thrown by assertEqual. In the catch block I will call my function to write stuff to word document and then raise the exception again so that old behaviour of a failing unit test is still happening.

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        try:
            x = 1
            y = 2
            self.assertEqual(x, y)
        except AssertionError:
            writeToDocument(x, y, self.id().split('.')[-1], 'These values should be equal')
            raise

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

At least thats what I thought. I think I am missing something. I see this error when I run the test. This error is raised at the point where I raise the exception after calling my documentation method.

```
RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise
```

Any ideas where I am messing up on the exception handling stuff?

Comment: It might be a trivial formatting error in this question, but your indentation is wrong. Is your `raise` statement really indented under the `except` statement, or does it occur *after* the whole `try/except` statement?

Comment: I have indented it under except. So that once I am in the except block I call the documentation function and then call raise. Unless this is not as per indentation rules. I am coming from c# land and the indentation thing is not my strong area.

Comment: Be sure you aren't mixing tabs and spaces; a single tab would appear to be *two* levels of 4-space indents if you are using 8-space tab stops, but would only be treated as *one* level of indentation by the Python parser.

Comment: I am using PyCharm studio to avoid the indentation issues. I press tab in the studio to indent. I hope the editor has whole story sorted out.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the call to `writeToDocument`?

Comment: Try using `except AssertionError as err` and `raise err`, and let us know what happens. I wasn't able to reproduce your original problem when I comment out the writeToDocument line.

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon It works !! Kindly put that as an answer. There was a similar answer but the poster deleted the answer. Can there be any issue in this answer which he saw a reason fit for deletion?

Comment: Great! I can't imagine any issues with it, so I think probably not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's losing the reference to the error somehow, try passing it explicitly using `except AssertionError as err`.

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        try:
            x = 1
            y = 2
            self.assertEqual(x, y)
        except AssertionError as err:
            writeToDocument(x, y, self.id().split('.')[-1], 'These values should be equal')
            raise err

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```