# How active exception to reraise in Python(3.8<=)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

look at this:

```py
RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise
```

I use `raise`. with out error like this:

```py
class example:
    def __getattribute__(self, attr_name):
        raise  # I mean: AttributeError: '...' object has no attribute '...'
```

This is [raise statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement):

```
raise_stmt ::=  "raise" [expression ["from" expression]]
```

expression is OPTIONAL.

I check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46396410/), but this isn't my answer. if error says "No active exception to reraise", so I can active an error. I do not know what this error means. My question is, what is meant by "active exception" and where it is used? Does it help make the code shorter and more optimized? Is it possible to use it for the task I showed a little higher in the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [raise with no argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001721/raise-with-no-argument)

Comment: It is a close question, but my question has other purposes as well

Comment: Can you clarify your question? A bare ``raise`` ["re-raises the last exception that was active in the current scope"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement). There isn't any active exception in your code, and that's exactly what the error is saying.

Comment: I need default error for attribute `AttributeError: '...' object has no attribute '...'`

Comment: There is no such thing as a default error. The ``AttributeError`` you allude to is actively raised by some code – if you don't invoke it, Python has no way of knowing which error you mean.

Comment: so What does "No active exception to reraise" mean?

Comment: You can only use `raise` by itself if you're in an `except` block. It reraises the exception that just got caught.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46396410) refutes your claim

Comment: @Blckknght
sorry you sentence is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `raise` keyword barely, Python tries to re-raise the currently occurred exception in the current scope, If there is no exception triggered on, you will get `RuntimeError: No active exception to re-raise`.

To see which exception is active(being handled), you can use [`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info):

```
import sys

try:
    raise ZeroDivisionError()
except ZeroDivisionError:
    type_, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
    print(type_)  # <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>
```

In the above except block you can use bare `raise` keyword, which re-raised the `ZeroDivisionError` exception for you.

If there is no active exception, the returned value of `sys.exc_info()` is `(None, None, None)`. So you have to use `raise` keyword followed by a subclass or an instance of [BaseException](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException). This is the case in your question inside `__getattribute__` method since there is no active exception.

```
class Example:
    def __getattribute__(self, attr_name):
        raise AttributeError(f'Error for "{attr_name}".')

obj  = Example()
obj.foo   # AttributeError: Error for "foo".
```

From comments:

*Active exception* means the exception that is currently triggered on, and is in the workflow, If you don't catch it and let it bubbles up, it will terminate the process.

Comment: I will clarify this a bit, but my question is how does this change and how do I use it

Comment: @Delta As I said in the answer you could use raise keyword followed by the exception you intend to raise. like : `raise AttributeError("'...' object has no attribute '...'")`.

Comment: My question is: `what is meant by "active exception" and where it is used? Does it help make the code shorter and more optimized? Is it possible to use it for the task I showed a little higher in the code?` this is answer of first one. what about others?

Comment: @Delta Check updated answer , Now I think I already answered your questions about what bare `raise` keyword does and when/where you can use it.

Comment: I think I did not ask my questions correctly. I want use `raise` without defining an exception to my problem and can use this method. I am sorry and thanks you for your answer and time.

Comment: sorry you answer is correct. I did not understand what you meant at that time. When I started searching in other places, I understood what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

I can find this for my questions:

##### what is meant by "active exception" and where it is used?

then using [`try-except`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) and code goes to `except` block, error actives.
about usage we can check error and if Should not be handled, can use
`raise` without arg (Even In Functions). now error raised without
Reference to line. I do not know if there is another way to do this or not, but I was convinced of this method.

Example:

```py
>>> try:
...     10 / 0
... except[ ZeroDivisionError[ as err]]:
...     raise
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
>>> def test():
...     raise
... 
>>> try:
...     10 / 0
... except[ ZeroDivisionError[ as err]]:
...     test()
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
>>>
```

##### Does it help make the code shorter and more optimized?

Yes. By using this method, the code and error are shortened. But in this method, there is less control over the exception procedure, which can sometimes be problematic.

##### Is it possible to use it for the task I showed a little higher in the code?

No. [`NotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented) must be returned for the above code to take effect. I have full confidence in this, but there is a possibility that this alone is not enough.